# WPF datagrid question

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and it works great but I notice some sort of very tiny column before the first column ...I want to remove it ....How do I do it ?

Take a look at the picture: 
 http://i45.tinypic.com/2d177f9.jpg
...the thing I want to remove is what I surrounded in the red rectangle.

Comment: See my answer, it's easy once you know what it is :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the row header.  When you click on it, it selects the whole row. By default it looks like a weird artifact like you mentionned.

Just set the property like this RowHeaderWidth="0" and it will disappear, or set it to bigger to see it better.

Comment: it was really hard to find any result related to this issue specially that the only link i found on the internet so far have the title "WPF datagrid question" which is out of context lol, but im glad i found your answer cause that issue annoyed me for a long time and im happy that there is even a solution for it lol , thank you David . i really appreciate you

Answer (score 2):

It's the row header as David Brunelle said. But instead of setting it's width to zero, I think cleaner solution is to set `HeadersVisibility="Column"`.

Comment: Didn't know that one. Gonna check that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
     <my:DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Name="softwareTable" Width="542" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False">
                <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="182" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Width="350" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                </my:DataGrid.Columns>
            </my:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this at runtime or design time.  I put this xaml into vs2008 and had no indication of a problem.

Comment: It's only going to be runtime. One thing I don't like with datagrids in WPF is that some formating only happen when data is in the grid. So if your grid is empty,you don't see it.

Answer (score -1):

I think u have problem with first column. 
your grid width is 542 and u set 182 for first column and set 350 for second column.
just simple math **350+182=532**

u see 532 not 542

two solution 
1: add 10 to first column width

or

2: decrease 10 from grid width
I hop it help

Comment: This will create a gap on the right, not the left. Nice thinking though, but it's really juste the row header.

Comment: Answer is complete !
nice tip i don't know about that